# html radio checked = "checked" property not working with jquery simplemodal on ipad / safari

Tags: jquery, safari, simplemodal, checked, radio-group

I am using

> jquery simplemodal

to show popup box on screen. I dynamically append html to this simplemodal box on different button clicks. The HTML contains radio groups with one default selected in each group. The default selection appears on all browsers except safari. I need the default selection on safari browser.
Below is a sample html that i am appending to simple modal.

```
        <div>
            <b>How would you like your patty to be done ?
                <can only choose one>
            </b>
        </div>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="Rare" name="patty" /><input type="hidden"
                        for="Rare" value="0" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    Rare
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="Medium Rare" name="patty" /><input type="hidden" for="Medium Rare"
                        value="0" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    Medium Rare
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="Medium" name="patty" /><input type="hidden" for="Medium"
                        value="0" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    Medium
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="Medium Well" name="patty" /><input type="hidden" for="Medium Well"
                        value="0" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    Medium Well
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="Well Done" name="patty" /><input type="hidden" for="Well Done"
                        value="0" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    Well Done
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div>
            <b>Choose your side.
                <can choose only one>
            </b>
        </div>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="Salad" name="side" /><input type="hidden"
                        for="Salad" value="0" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    Salad
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="Fries" name="side" /><input type="hidden" for="Fries"
                        value="0" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    Fries
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="Onion Rings" name="side" /><input type="hidden" for="Onion Rings"
                        value="3" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    Onion Rings (Extra 3.0)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="Truffle Fries" name="side" /><input type="hidden" for="Truffle Fries"
                        value="3" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    Truffle Fries (Extra 3.0)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" value="Spam Fries" name="side" /><input type="hidden" for="Spam Fries"
                        value="3" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    Spam Fries (Extra 3.0)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

EDIT : This is occuring on IOS 5 and not on IOS 6.

Comment: You mean `checked="checked"` not working?

Comment: yes, its not working in simplemodal box on safari